# Compute end date for project

Tags: java, datetime

The aim of this method: based on `toDate` (from UI), generate End Limit Date for the Project.

```
 /**
 * Return correct From Limit Date according the logic of start and end date of current project.
 *
 * @param project current project
 * @param toDate to date from UI form
 * @return correct to date for project holder
 */
private static Calendar getCorrectToDateLimit(final Project project,final Date toDate) {
    if (toDate != null) {
        final Calendar toFormDate = AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(toDate);
        //check have the  project  end date
        if (project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate() != null) {
            final Calendar projectEnd = AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate());
            if (toFormDate.after(projectEnd)) {
                final String validationMessage = Messages.get("validation.absence_details_report.to.date.later.end");
                renderArgs.put("toDate-error-" + project.id, validationMessage);
                return projectEnd;
            } else {
               return toFormDate;
            }
        } else {
            //in case of ongoing project
            return AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(toDate);
        }
    } else {
        //in case of nullable toDate check - if  project have end date - return project end date / else current date
       return (project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate() != null) ?
               AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate()) : Calendar.getInstance();
    }
}
```

AbsenceHelper:

```
public static Calendar getCalFromDate(final Date date) {
    final Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();
    result.setTime((Date)date.clone());
    return result;
}
```

How can I make this method more readable?

Comment: It's hard to tell what calculation you are trying to perform, based on this little excerpt of code that you have shown. Please describe what you are trying to accomplish, and show the code behind the methods that you are calling.

Comment: update code. Calculation like this: i recive from UI to Date limit for some report. And i need to make a report with end date in logic like this: toDafe from form - not null -> project have end date ?  { and toDate from form later than end of project - return end of project} else return toDate from UI form. IN case nullable toDate from form: project have end date ? return project.endDate / else return toDate from UI form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Put the code through a linter. This will tell you about things like missing spaces and other easy wins.
- Pass the relevant `project` properties instead of the entire `project` ([Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter))
- Flatten your `if` hierarchy, either by pulling out four methods and deciding which to call in the callers or by creating basically a `switch` statement using the project details mentioned.
- [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - there are four calls to `AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate`, two checks for `project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate() != null`, and three calls to `project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm avoiding Law of Demeter with calling in methods only specialized field of objects. Additionally, I divide in a separate method, `getCorrectToDateLimitWithNotNullToDate(projectId, lastProjectDate, toDate)`, for more a suitable reading of a `if` hierarchy. I also avoid repeating myself with `AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate` and `project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate() != null`.

```
private static Calendar getCorrectToDateLimit(final Long projectId, final Date lastProjectDate, final Date toDate) {
    if (toDate != null) {
        return getCorrectToDateLimitWithNotNullToDate(projectId, lastProjectDate, toDate);
    } else {
        return (lastProjectDate != null) ? AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(lastProjectDate) : Calendar.getInstance();
    }
}

private static Calendar getCorrectToDateLimitWithNotNullToDate(Long projectId, Date lastProjectDate, Date toDate) {
    final Calendar toFormDate = AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(toDate);

    if (lastProjectDate != null) {
        final Calendar projectEnd = AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate(lastProjectDate);
        if (toFormDate.after(projectEnd)) {
            final String validationMessage = Messages.get("validation.absence_details_report.to.date.later.end");
            renderArgs.put("toDate-error-" + projectId, validationMessage);
            return projectEnd;
        }
    }
    //in case of toDate early than end of project or for ongoing projects
    return toFormDate;
}
```

Comment: You must also explain how this improves upon the original code.  Answers with only code can be deleted.

Comment: i'm avoid Low of Demeter with calling in methods only specialized field of objects. Additional i devide in separate methode getCorrectToDateLimitWithNotNullToDate(projectId, lastProjectDate, toDate); for more suitable reading of if hierarhy. And delete reapiting of myself with AbsenceHelper.getCalFromDate and project.getLastWorkOrderEndDate() != null.